# Google Maps API Countries and Regions as Polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, gis

I've got a question about highlighting areas on Google map. I know how to place polygons on map. It's pretty simple and straghtforward. The problem is I don't have access to such data and I don't know any source of it. From my database I get lat/lon for a specific place and I need to have data about their borders. Do you know any free or paid database that contains such polygons data for all countries/regions in the world?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.gelib.com/world-borders.htm
There is a .kml file at this location you can use as a starting point.

Comment: gelib.com link is dead

Answer (score 4):

With this tool you can create any polygon you like:
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/googletool.html