# polygon like outline to a place border when user enters a place name in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am working on a web project where I want my user to enter a place name(place name could be city, state, country) which will produce a polygon connecting the borders of that place or those points will be given to me so that I could draw a polygon on Google Map myself. Is there any option to get the list of lat and longs of borders (though I am getting four set of lat longs through (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=India&sensor=false) however that draws a rectangle which I don't want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Countries and Regions as Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877351/google-maps-api-countries-and-regions-as-polygons)

Comment: @derylius Okay, do I have to install google earth to download that kml file from "Gregory A Beamer" answer? Do that file consist of all border outlines city,country wise?

Comment: Found this after 1min of googling:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/?hl=hu&csw=1
Show a bit more effort please!

Comment: I did that already @derylius and downloaded the country kml however I am not sure how to make things happen for particular city or state. I referred 
http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/source/browse/branches/ng/examples/src/data/worldmap.kml
which gives almost all countries' boundary. another thing is that I downloaded a .shp file for all references, I am trying to convert it into kml using expertgps.... Please let me know if you have any update regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: parse the kml(xml) file  and use the following  api to draw them on google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines If you need anything else, you surely gonna find it in the API documentation, please write again only if you read the whole documentation and something is missing from it.

Comment: @derylius, I already parsed and draw polygons for countries....I meant to say what if my user require further more details like they want to see border outline of a city lets say "Paris", how would I get the set of lat long of border of that city.

Comment: I just need the datasource or set of border points(lat,long) of all cities of world...all drawing thing I can take care of myself. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The cities' and countries' borders are available here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/id/%3Aplace_id

This is the source google maps using. To search for placeID based on name, use this:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/search

Comment: Thanx I tried that before however some are saying this is not giving 100 percent result and the main question is how would I get the place id from the place name.

Comment: You can use this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/search just set granularity to city, this way it finds cities as well as countries.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it answered your question, or comment why not!!!