# Given Lat/Lng get polygon

Tags: c#, google-maps, gis

Is there a way using Google Maps API or any other API to know a specific point in which region it exists and get the polygon for that region?

I know that with Google Maps API i can get several info like political areas etc, but how can i get the polygon defining them?

I am interested in knowing the Region or City boundaries, not the country's.

Preferably i would like something to use in a console application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Countries and Regions as Polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877351/google-maps-api-countries-and-regions-as-polygons)

Comment: @SteveBenett Thanks for this, but i have already seen it. It states that it has info for countries, though i am interested in Cities / Regions.

Comment: Ok, got you. The only service I know with such a functionality is the Overpass API of OSM. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499511/how-can-i-get-the-city-borders-for-a-country.

Comment: Sounds extremely promising. :-) I will have a look shortly.

Comment: @SteveBenett Your comments have helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **`Steve Benett`**'s comments, i finally got the start of the thread that led me to an answer.

First i got on the [proposed link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499511/how-can-i-get-the-city-borders-for-a-country), which led me clicking on a [SO like question](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/19336/get-city-borders-for-finland) on [openstreetmap](https://help.openstreetmap.org/)'s help page.

After that i asked [my own question](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/36830/given-latlng-get-polygon) there hoping that someone could have a more relevant info on what i am looking for.

Right there i got yet another comment suggesting i use their [Nominatim service](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) to get the name of the region that the given coordinates belong to.

Having that info, i could use the same service to request the polygon defining that area.

Finally for whoever wants to see an example of that, i created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eocw2jv2/1/) utilizing these services. Just fill in the two input boxes with lat and lng of the point you want to check, and you will end up with a map with the requested area marked.

Just in case jsfiddle goes wrong this is my code. It is not perfect but does the job. There are some known issues with that (check after the code for these):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="lat" value="36.5100710" />
    <input type="text" id="lng" value="-4.8824474" />
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var boundingbox = [];
var geojson = [];
var getMap = function (lat, lng) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            lat: lat,
            lon: lng
        },
        type: 'GET'
    }).success(function (region) {
        //console.log(region);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search',
            data: {
                format: 'json',
                country: region.address.country,
                state: region.address.state,
                polygon_geojson: 1
            },
            type: 'GET'
        }).success(function (data) {
            boundingbox = data[0].boundingbox;
            if (data[0].geojson.type == 'Polygon') {
                console.log(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0]);
                $.each(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0], function (i) {
                    geojson.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][i][1], data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][i][0]));
                });
            } else {
                console.log(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][0]);
                $.each(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][0], function (i) {
                    geojson.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][0][i][1], data[0].geojson.coordinates[0][0][i][0]));
                });
            }
            //console.log([boundingbox, geojson]);
        }).then(function () {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                //zoom: 12,
                //center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.2265968, 4.5504552),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var requestedPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: geojson,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            });
            //console.log(bermudaTriangle);
            requestedPolygon.setMap(map);
            var a = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(boundingbox[0]), parseFloat(boundingbox[2]));
            var b = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(boundingbox[1]), parseFloat(boundingbox[3]));;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend(a);
            bounds.extend(b);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        })
    })
}
$(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        console.log("s");
        var lat = $("#lat").val();
        var lng = $("#lng").val();
        getMap(lat, lng);
    });
});
```

**Known Issues**

- There are cases that the returned type is a multipolygon which is actually an array of polygons. In my sample i get the first polygon only, which s wrong, but this is just a show case and not the final solution.
- If you change region then it does not clear the previous region and somewhat connects them.